# Force image to reload in Android webkit/phonegap

Tags: android, html, webkit, cordova

Does anyone know how to force an image to reload in Android webkit?

I'm building and HTML-app with phonegap, where the user is allows to change his/her profile photo by uploading a new one from the camera. But the browser keeps displaying the old image until I browse to another page and back to the "profile page". Very annoying!

I've tried adding a timestamp to the url as below, which I know work with most desktop browsers. Not here though.

actual url:
/my/image/url.jpg

switched to:
/my/image/url.jpg?12345678 (<-- current time in millis)

Any ideas on what to do?

Once the image is uploaded I use window.location = same/url/again.jsp to reload the page. But no luck there. The image is only reloaded once I browse to another page and back again..

Comment: You can change it using javascript or jQuery. Find the image element and change it's source?